# Why do we get low amount of featured questions?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I rarely find featured questions on SciFi.SE and the number is zero at this time. This is uncommon to many SE sites I have used.

Why do we get low amount of featured questions?

Comment: I would guess it's due to the number of questions we get per day. Since it's generally quite low, questions aren't often overlooked and as a result the main reason of placing a bounty on them - to attract more attention - doesn't necessarily apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I take it you ask more why this site encourages so much less bounties than sites like [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) (**390** bounties), [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) (**28** bounties) or [SU](https://superuser.com/?tab=featured) (**23** bounties). Despite SO clearly being significantly larger than [scifi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) (**0** bounties), there is another significant difference between the sites listed above and sites like this one or say [movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) (**0** bounties).

The first category is a set of sites where things get asked where people, *even experienced ones* (`*`), get stuck on problems affecting their profession. The second category is frequented mostly by people in the context of their entertainment and private life (`**`). Although scifi and fantasy fans can get really invested in their favourite franchise, it's still a difference if you cannot solve an (even remotely) job-related problem or if you don't understand a finer point of some entertainment programme.

Example; If you have a deadline in 5 days and have been trying to solve a problem with your program for the last 3 days (with still a lot of work to do before the deadline), you might be willing to spend and increasingly large amount of your SO rep, if it can get you a solution. You might be willing to offer a bounty of 500 if you're desperate (and possibly more than just one, if the system allows it); but if you don't get an answer here (at SFF), just shrugging the question off might be an option.

---

`*`: these are the ones that can spend large bounties!
`**`: yes, I know there are exceptions; We do have some professional scifi/fantasy writers/contributors on the site, but they are a minority.

Answer (score 2):

There is a low amount of featured questions because nobody sees a need to put bounty on questions.

You are probably a good person to answer why; As I'm writing, you [asked 190 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931/sachin-shekhar?tab=questions) and [never placed any bounties yet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931/sachin-shekhar?tab=bounties&sort=offered).

I guess people love their *hard* gained reputation too much to *waste* it on a bounty.

Comment: Unable to understand second paragraph.. You can place a bounty on other's question, too. And, why is last paragraph not applicable to other SE sites?

Comment: @SachinShekhar Q1 - My second paragraph mean : "nobody see a need to put bounty" --> "You never placed a bounties yet" (on your questions nor on other's question) --> Ask yourself why you never placed a bounties and you will have a good idea why nobody placed a bounty.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Q2 - I have no idea, it's just speculation... Maybe because as a non technical SE, users don't *need* answer as bad as for a technical SE.

Comment: I beg to differ; [Some people](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2565/bitmask?tab=bounties) offered over a tenth of their overall rep in bounties (I bet there is even more on other accounts). That is over 1k rep in my case; However, I don't remember any of those ever producing any extra answers that were actually helpful.

Comment: There a [top investors query](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/97626/top-investors) that list the users that spent rep on bounties.

Comment: I find [the relative sort](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/97655/top-investors-relative-sort) much more interesting. :)

Comment: @bitmask - I think some people (ISTR keen) put bounties just for the hell of it (as in, with the **GOAL** of reducing their rep, based on chat comments in the past).

Comment: @DVK: I think its more a kind of site promotion.

Comment: Indeed. For a time I sought to minimize my rep gains, but I did so using bounties on posts that I wanted to draw more attention to. It's nice to see what a massive proportion of my total rep I managed to expend though.

Comment: @bitmask High-five, fellow >10%er. :)

Comment: @Keen: High-five, but I'm not sure I'm going to keep it up. It has been my experience that bounties produce quantity but not quality at horrific relations.

Answer (score 2):

As [the featured page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) states when there are no featured questions:

> **There are no questions with an [active bounty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) at the moment.**
>
> **Would you like to [open a bounty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) on one of your questions — or someone else's?**

So the reason there aren't many featured questions is that there aren't many people bountying questions.